# Definition of an algebra on a set

Tags: real-analysis

### Definition

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$. The family $\mathcal{E}$ is elemental if:

1. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{E}$;
2. $E \cap F \in \mathcal{E}$ for each $E , F \in \mathcal{E}$;
3. For all $E \in \mathcal{E}$, there is a finite family ${\{E_i\}}_{i = 1}^n \subset \mathcal{E}$, with $E_i \cap E_j = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$, such that
   $$
   E^c = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n E_i\mbox{.}
   $$

---

I want to prove that
$$
\mathcal{A} = \left\{\bigcup_{i = 1}^n E_i : {\{E_i\}}_{i = 1}^n \mbox{ is a disjoint family in } \mathcal{E} \right\}
$$
is an algebra on $X$. I have already proved that $X \in \mathcal{A}$ and $E^c \in \mathcal{A}$ if $E \in \mathcal{A}$. Fixed $E , F \in \mathcal{A}$, I want to show now that $E \cup F \in \mathcal{A}$. We have that
$$
E = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n E_i \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad F = \bigcup_{j = 1}^m F_i\mbox{,}
$$
being ${\{E_i\}}_{i = 1}^n$ and ${\{F_i\}}_{j = 1}^m$ two disjoint families in $\mathcal{E}$, so we can write
$$
E \cup F = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{n + m} A_k\mbox{,}
$$
where
$$
A_k = \left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
E_k & \mbox{ if } & k \leq n\mbox{;}
\\
F_{k - n} & \mbox{ if } & k > n\mbox{.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
If we fix $k , l \in \{1 , \ldots , n + m\}$, then $A_k \cap A_l = \emptyset$ if $k \leq n$ and $l \leq n$ or $k > n$ and $l > n$, so only I need to show that $A_k \cap A_l = \emptyset$ if $k \leq n$ and $l > n$ or $k > n$ and $l \leq n$. The two cases have the same difficulty, so we suppose for example that $k \leq n$ and $l > n$. In this case, $A_k = E_k$ and $A_l = F_{l - n}$. How can I prove that $E_k \cap F_{l - n} = \emptyset$? My attemps have no result. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have proved that $\mathcal A$ is closed under complement, it's easier to prove first that if $E, F\in\mathcal{A}$ then $E\cap F\in\mathcal{A}$ and then use the fact that $$E\cup F=(E^c\cap F^c)^c.$$

To prove that $E\cap F\in\mathcal{A}$, simply observe that $$E\cap F=\bigcup_\limits{i,j} E_i\cap F_j$$
is a partition by elements of $\mathcal E$ as required.

Comment: @joseabp91 you're welcome!